# gyp Failing when Installing pg-native

Tags: node.js, macos, libpq, gyp

I'm trying to install the `pg-native` package:

```
sudo npm install pg-native
```

but the following error is generated:

```
> libpq@1.7.0 install /Workspace/auth/node_modules/libpq
> node-gyp rebuild

/bin/sh: pg_config: command not found
gyp: Call to 'pg_config --libdir' returned exit status 127. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:355:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.0.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/4.1.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Workspace/auth/node_modules/libpq
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN install:libpq libpq@1.7.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:libpq Exit status 1
```

I've tried remedying this by installing the `node-gyp` module and then running the rebuild command manually:

```
sudo npm install -g node-gyp
sudo node-gyp rebuild
```

I read that this issue no longer persists in more current versions of Node, so I updated to version `v4.1.1`.

I've also tried a mix of installing the modules locally to the workspace and globally to the rest of the machine, but still no luck. Running `node-gyp` works, so it looks like that has been properly installed.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not sure why I didn't think of this originally, but this was resolved by [installing `libpq` on my local machine](https://superuser.com/questions/296873/install-libpq-dev-on-mac-os).

```
brew install postgresql
```

This bundle comes with `libpq`, which I didn't realize was needed at first, given the ambiguity in the error message.

It looked like it was either installed, or installing as a prerequisite since the first line in the error message identified a version number for this package, `libpq@1.7.0`.

Comment: Prerequisites mentioned in original doc (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-native)

Comment: Very similar error where solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74715990/node-gyp-err-invalid-mode-ru-while-trying-to-load-binding-gyp