# Getting errors while trying to add Swagger to node.js project

Tags: node.js, swagger-ui

In my node.js project (version 14.18.2) I want to add `Swagger UI`.

When i'm trying to use some article from the web, it tells me to add `swagger-jsdoc` and `swagger-ui-express` as dependencies.

While the installation is running, im getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 50, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 554, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 547, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 520, in gyp_main
    [generator, flat_list, targets, data] = Load(
                                            ^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 136, in Load
    result = gyp.input.Load(build_files, default_variables, includes[:],
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 2782, in Load
    LoadTargetBuildFile(build_file, data, aux_data,
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 391, in LoadTargetBuildFile
    build_file_data = LoadOneBuildFile(build_file_path, data, aux_data,
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 234, in LoadOneBuildFile
    build_file_contents = open(build_file_path, 'rU').read()
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid mode: 'rU' while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/user/Documents/project/project-BackEnd/node_modules/node/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user/Documents/project/project-BackEnd/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v13.14.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN @apidevtools/swagger-parser@10.0.2 requires a peer of openapi-types@>=7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node gyp ERR - invalid mode: 'rU' while trying to load binding.gyp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74715990/113116)

Comment: @Helen I have no python installed and no canvas as part of my packahe.json file, should python be installed in my env to download those dependencies ?